# $http status 0 angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm developing a mobile application using ionic and angular. I have a problem when invoking `$http` post function sometimes it works but sometimes it does not. When it does not, it return status 0. It is not a CORS because it sometimes works.

The architecture of the app: device <-> internet <-> apache http server <-> Tomcat Server.

Anyone can help?

Thanks,

Comment: Status code 0 means that there is something wrong with the back-end of your application, it's not responding. Or it could also be your connection, but i doubt that.

Comment: I think my connection is fine, and I didn't get any error log in my backend

Comment: One more reason for this - the request is getting cancelled because of timeout.

Comment: Already set timeout for 2 min, but before 2 min, the error is coming.